# JavaScript/PHP libraries for calculating common

Tags: software, javascript, php

I am looking for a `JavaScript` or a `PHP` library to calculate common business/statistical metrics (e.g. `Total`, `Avg`, `YTD`, `YoY`, `MoM`, `CAGR` growth, standard deviation, regression line coordinates) from simple arrays/objects with a structure such as:

[image]

The idea is that I would just provide the arrays with some basic parameters (e.g. time period I'm interested in) and would get all the numbers crunched automatically in return.

**Can anybody point me to a library they've used and trust from experience?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use http://d3js.org/
or http://simplystatistics.org/tag/d3-js/
Or you can find another javascript library with stats methods